# remove disabled attribute for each option in select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select with different options. I set as disabled options that have been used in the last 30 seconds. What I am trying to get is to enable again the options when the criteria is no more valid but WHILE the page is still open.
The following code works for one option but since it is inside .each() it is overwritten for each option and it doesn't work. 
I was thinking about a workaround storing the diff value, adding a class to the element and running set timeout on items with that class but I think this kind of code is not the most efficient. 
Any idea on how to get the same result with a more efficient code (inside the each loop maybe?).

```
$('#destinatario option').each(function(){
    var ds = $(this).attr('data-ts'); 
    console.log("ts vale "+ds);
    var dateArray = ds.split(" ");  // split the date and time 
    var ds1 = dateArray[0].split("-"); // split each parts in date
    var ds2 = dateArray[1].split(":"); // split each parts in time
    var newDate = new Date(ds1[0], (+ds1[1] - 1), ds1[2], ds2[0], ds2[1], ds2[2]).getTime(); //parse it
    console.log("allora vale "+newDate);
    var currentDate = new Date().getTime();
    console.log("adesso vale "+currentDate);
    var diff = currentDate - newDate;
    console.log(diff);
    if(diff < 30000){
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).prop('disabled', false);
        }, (30000-diff));
    }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614521/settimeout-not-working-with-jquery-each-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same situation, where the problem i have a loop and want to bind for each in loop a callback for change and i found all of them are work for only last id and to solve it i did the following to bind the parameter when call the callback so it save the state:

```
var arr = ["id1" ,"id2", "id3"];
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  jQuery("#form_target_input").bind('change',function (id, e){
    yiel.fn.setCookie("form_targeting_"+id, true)
   }.bind(null, id));
 }
```

for your case:

```
setTimeout(function(element, e) {
   $(element).prop('disabled', false);
}.bind(null, this), (30000-diff));
```

Comment: I prefer not to use .bind I solved moving the set timeout outside the each function (it does the same of your code actually).

Comment: yes, it do the same trick the idea here is to know why that happen finding the problem is the hard part solving has many ways.

Comment: In this case: each is a loop so setTimeout is overwritten every time. Bind duplicates the setTimeout and voila!

Answer (score 1):

try to change the last part:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);
}.bind(this), (30000-diff));
```